# Google Sheets | ReferenceError: shUserForm is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a User Form to submit Properties into a Database. The user will insert the data into the form and click submit to write the new input into the database. I have not yet had it work as i keep getting an error code.

I am getting the Error "ReferenceError: shUserForm is not defined" when submitting my form in Google Sheets. I have tried everything. maybe there is something I am missing.

Please help!

```js
//Function to validate the entry made by user in Property Form

function validateEntry() {

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //to create the instance of the user interface to show the alert

  shUserForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FFFFFF');

  //Validating Street #
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C7").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street #");
    shUserForm.getRange("C7").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Prefix
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C9").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Prefix");
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Street Name
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C11").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Name");
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Suffix
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C13").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Suffix");
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating City
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C15").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter City");
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating State
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C17").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter State");
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating County
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C19").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter County");
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Zip Code
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C21").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Zip Code");
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Property Type
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C24").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Type");
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Year Built
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C26").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Year Built");
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating SQFT
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C28").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Sq ft");
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Bed
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C30").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bedroom count");
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Bath
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C32").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bathroom count");
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}

//Function to submit the data to the Database sheet

function submitData() {

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");

  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  //to create the instance of the UI environmentto use the alert features

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking the user response

  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {

    return; //to exit from this function
  }

  if (validateEntry() == true) {

    var blankRow = datasheet.getLastRow() + 1; //identify the next blank row

    //code to update database

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Street #

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C9").getValue()); //Prefix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C11").getValue()); //Street Name

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C13").getValue()); //suffix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C15").getValue()); //city
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C17").getValue()); //state
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C19").getValue()); //County
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C21").getValue()); //Zip
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C24").getValue()); //Property Type
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C26").getValue()); //Year Built
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C28").getValue()); //Sqft
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C30").getValue()); //bed
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 14).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C32").getValue()); //bath

    //Code to update the date and time

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');

    //Submitted By

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 16).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - Property ' + shUserForm.getRange("C11").getValue() + '"');

    shUserForm.getRange("C7").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").clear();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

***FINDINGS:***

> It looks the error is due to 2 redundant instances of the variable `shUserForm` that exists in `validateEntry` & `submitData` functions. When I changed the name of the `shUserForm` inside of the `submitData` function, the script runs fine.

***SOLUTION:***

I have tweaked your script to only use one `shUserForm` variable for both functions. Then, I've renamed `shUserForm` to `userForm` (for some reason the error *`ReferenceError: shUserForm is not defined`* still occurs if the original name is used).

Just only run the `validateEntry` function and it should first run the validation & then the `submitData` function (if all of the required cells weren't empty).

***TWEAKED SCRIPT:***

```
//Function to validate the entry made by user in Property Form

function validateEntry() {

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var userForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");
  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //to create the instance of the user interface to show the alert

  userForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  userForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FFFFFF');

  //Validating Street #
  if (userForm.getRange("C7").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street #");
    userForm.getRange("C7").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Prefix
  if (userForm.getRange("C9").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Prefix");
    userForm.getRange("C9").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Street Name
  if (userForm.getRange("C11").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Name");
    userForm.getRange("C11").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Suffix
  if (userForm.getRange("C13").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Suffix");
    userForm.getRange("C13").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating City
  if (userForm.getRange("C15").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter City");
    userForm.getRange("C15").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating State
  if (userForm.getRange("C17").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter State");
    userForm.getRange("C17").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating County
  if (userForm.getRange("C19").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter County");
    userForm.getRange("C19").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Zip Code
  if (userForm.getRange("C21").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Zip Code");
    userForm.getRange("C21").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Property Type
  if (userForm.getRange("C24").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Type");
    userForm.getRange("C24").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Year Built
  if (userForm.getRange("C26").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Year Built");
    userForm.getRange("C26").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating SQFT
  if (userForm.getRange("C28").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Sq ft");
    userForm.getRange("C28").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Bed
  if (userForm.getRange("C30").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bedroom count");
    userForm.getRange("C30").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }

  //Validating Bath
  if (userForm.getRange("C32").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bathroom count");
    userForm.getRange("C32").activate();
    userForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return;
  }
  
  //Run submitData() if all required cells are not empty
  submitData(true, userForm, datasheet);

}

//Function to submit the data to the Database sheet

function submitData(booleanValue, userForm, datasheet) {

  //to create the instance of the UI environmentto use the alert features
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking the user response

  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {

    return; //to exit from this function
  }

  if (booleanValue == true) {

    var blankRow = datasheet.getLastRow() + 1; //identify the next blank row

    //code to update database

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(userForm.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Street #

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(userForm.getRange("C9").getValue()); //Prefix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(userForm.getRange("C11").getValue()); //Street Name

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(userForm.getRange("C13").getValue()); //suffix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(userForm.getRange("C15").getValue()); //city
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(userForm.getRange("C17").getValue()); //state
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(userForm.getRange("C19").getValue()); //County
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(userForm.getRange("C21").getValue()); //Zip
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(userForm.getRange("C24").getValue()); //Property Type
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(userForm.getRange("C26").getValue()); //Year Built
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(userForm.getRange("C28").getValue()); //Sqft
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(userForm.getRange("C30").getValue()); //bed
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 14).setValue(userForm.getRange("C32").getValue()); //bath

    //Code to update the date and time

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');

    //Submitted By

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 16).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - Property ' + userForm.getRange("C11").getValue() + '"');

    userForm.getRange("C7").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C9").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C11").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C13").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C15").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C17").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C19").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C21").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C24").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C26").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C28").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C30").clear();
    userForm.getRange("C32").clear();

  }

}
```

***SAMPLE RESULT:***

> Sample **User Form** sheet w/ sample data:

[image]

> The **Database** sheet after running the `validateEntry` function:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I updated the script but it is still not posting the values to the database on mine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Function to validate the entry made by user in Property Form

function validateEntry() {

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //to create the instance of the user interface to show the alert

  shUserForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FFFFFF');
  shUserForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FFFFFF');

  //Validating Street #
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C7").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street #");
    shUserForm.getRange("C7").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Prefix
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C9").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Prefix");
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Street Name
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C11").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Name");
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Suffix
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C13").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Street Suffix");
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating City
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C15").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter City");
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating State
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C17").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter State");
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating County
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C19").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter County");
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Zip Code
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C21").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Zip Code");
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Property Type
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C24").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Type");
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Year Built
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C26").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Year Built");
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating SQFT
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C28").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Property Sq ft");
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Bed
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C30").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bedroom count");
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  //Validating Bath
  if (shUserForm.getRange("C32").isBlank() == true) {

    ui.alert("Please enter Bathroom count");
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").activate();
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").setBackground('#FF0000');
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}

//Function to submit the data to the Database sheet

function submitData() {

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");

  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  //to create the instance of the UI environmentto use the alert features

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to submit the data?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //checking the user response

  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {

    return; //to exit from this function
  }

  if (validateEntry() == true) {

    var blankRow = datasheet.getLastRow() + 1; //identify the next blank row

    //code to update database

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Street #

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C9").getValue()); //Prefix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C11").getValue()); //Street Name

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C13").getValue()); //suffix

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C15").getValue()); //city
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C17").getValue()); //state
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C19").getValue()); //County
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C21").getValue()); //Zip
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C24").getValue()); //Property Type
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C26").getValue()); //Year Built
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C28").getValue()); //Sqft
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C30").getValue()); //bed
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 14).setValue(shUserform.getRange("C32").getValue()); //bath

    //Code to update the date and time

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');

    //Submitted By

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 16).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - Property ' + shUserForm.getRange("C11").getValue() + '"');

    shUserForm.getRange("C7").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C9").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C11").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C13").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C15").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C17").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C19").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C21").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C24").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C26").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C28").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C30").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("C32").clear();

  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).